# Get JsonApiAdapter.js to work with Ember CLI

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to add JsonApiAdpater to my Ember-cli project. This does not seem to work:

application.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.JsonApiAdapter.extend({
  host: AppnameENV.APP.API_HOST
});
```

If I use the RESTAdapter it gets the data from fortune.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
// export default DS.JsonApiAdapter.extend({
  host: AppnameENV.APP.API_HOST
});
```

Does anyone have a working example. I use Ember-cli 0.0.40 and fortune.js

Non Ember-cli examples are welcome too.

```
var fortune = require('fortune')
  , app = fortune({
    db: 'appname'
  })
.resource('post', {
  title: String,
  author: String,
  date: Date,
  excerpt: String,
  body: String
})
.listen(1337);
```

Comment: I have created a working example with the RESTadapter but can't get the JsonApiAdapter to work. https://github.com/broerse/ember-cli-blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add JsonApiSerializer to Serializers. See:

https://github.com/broerse/ember-cli-blog